# java - How to parse String to a signature byte[]

Tags: java, security, base64, primary-key, sign

I'm trying to obtain the byte[] that represents the signature that is in a String but keep receiving "java.security.SignatureException: invalid encoding for signature"

What i'm trying to do is to send a signed string and veryfying it at server, here is my code:

Here is where i sign my string to send it via Web Service:

```
Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("DSA");
signer.initSign(signerKey);
signer.update(someString)
byte[] signature = signer.sign();
newToken = someString + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);
```

Here is the server-side code to obtain the string and verify the whole thing with it:

```
byte [] sig = Base64.getDecoder().decode(stringSignature);
Signature verifier = Signature.getInstance("DSA");
verifier.initVerify(verifierPubKey);
verifier.update(token);
verified = verifier.verify(signature);
```

So, what's the best way to obtain a signature from a string that actually represents the signature i'm trying to verify?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

```
verified = verifier.verify(signature);
```

should be changed to this:

```
verified = verifier.verify(sig);
```

I'm guessing signature is the Base64 encoding or something, rather than the raw bytes you need.